# Dialog border padding issue in Visual Studio 2013 happens in release mode only

Tags: visual-studio-2013, border, createwindow

I have an app that generates dialogs dynamically.  I used to build it with Visual Studio 6.0.  Switched to VS2013 a while back, and made necessary adjustments to get it to build.  Never actually released the app until recently. Then a user noticed the Windows 7 Aero border padding problem (mentioned in another post on here) where my dialogs were ending up smaller than requested - i.e., the Aero border padding was being taken from my requested window size rather than added to it, so my controls are not properly centered in the window as requested.  I had set the border padding on my desktop to 1, so I never noticed the issue.

The really weird thing is that this does *not* happen when I build the app for debug. If I run the debug and release versions side-by-side, you can see that the dialogs differ in size by the thickness of the border padding. I'm guessing that the debug vs release versions of the system library linked in have different implementations of this behavior.

In my logic to construct these dialogs, I figure out how big the client area needs to be, and then add on the frame metrics before creating the window.  Is this incorrect - i.e., is there a 'more correct' way to do this that will work on all versions of Windows, and with all compilers.

Comment: I just found the GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXPADDEDBORDER) and tried adding 2 * that into my requested window size.  That mostly fixes the problem, but not completely.  The release version still gets a slightly smaller window than the debug version.  Oddly, I'd have expected the debug version's windows to simply increase by the same amount, but they didn't seem to.  It turns out that GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXPADDEDBORDER) returns 8 (the padding value I set in Aero to test this) in the release version of the app, but returns 0 in the debug version.  Is this nuts or what?

Comment: Here's another odd thing.  My app uses MDI, and I only create true popup dialogs if the MDI windows are maximized.  If not maximized, I just create the popups as MDI children.  In the debug version, when the MDI child 'popups' are not resizeable, I don't get border padding at all.  But in the release version, I do get border padding on non-resizeable MDI children.  Is this just a buggy VS2013 - would 2015 fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, kind of have an answer.  The release and debug versions report completely different values for the various border-related system metrics.

Debug:
SM_CXPADDEDBORDER=0, SM_CXBORDER=1, SM_CXSIZEFRAME=12, SM_CXFIXEDFRAME=3

Release:
SM_CXPADDEDBORDER=8, SM_CXBORDER=1, SM_CXSIZEFRAME=4,  SM_CXFIXEDFRAME=3

So, once I add all of these into my requested window size, both versions seem to work - although they produce different results.  Non-resizeable windows in the debug version don't get padded borders, and resizeable ones get a big border, but it's the 'size frame' not the 'padding' that causes it.

Interestingly, when I look at my project properties, the linker command line in the debug config has /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS",5.01", and in the release config it just has /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS.  I don't see that 5.01 in the actual myapp.vcxproj file, so I'm thinking VS 2013 inserts the ",5.01" dynamically for the debug configuration to specifically force some compatibility mode.  I tried to specify it in the linker "system" section, but my change didn't show up on the command line.  Anybody know if it's possible (or advisable) to set this manually?